# Why did my account sell less tokens than this account?

Tags: transactions, defi

in this transaction. I sold a certain token but im not sure why my account sold so little of that token compared to this other account.

my transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbc40a1f14c057beacf2ce73f6acb32f5cddb92972fb7baa09831c590389f3048

other guy's transaction:https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe6d6cfa57dd9b74df53fe6a06285096c2f74eabcf4d1a9cb4a4a928f92a156b8

Thanks.

Comment: Um, because the other account had more tokens to sell, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a non-standard token. You should be extra careful with tokens like this.